# Disable Drag To Reorder From phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

i have latest version of phpmyadmin 4.1.14 and want to remove **Drag to reorder** option from table column, i tried

```
$cfg['AjaxEnable'] = false;
```

but still not figure it out, is there any other option to do that?

Comment: you are messing up Mysql server with phpmyadmin that is a tool to interact with mysql server. What version of phpMyAdmin do you have?

Comment: ahhh sorry that is 4.1.14

Comment: just update my question with phpmyadmin version